# Excepciones c++ POO

Tags: c++, excepciones

Debo realizar un programa con la clase triángulo y luego crear una clase con las siguientes excepciones:

- Se emita un mensaje de error si alguno de los lados tuviera valor cero.
- Se emita un mensaje de error (a decisión propia) si alguno de los lados del triángulo fuera negativo.
- Se emita un mensaje de error si no se pudiera construir un triángulo (violación de la desigualdad triangular).
- Suponer que existe un método triangle resize(itn factor){….código…}; en la clase triángulo que nos permite escalar un objeto triángulo de acuerdo al factor introducido, ej: si el factor = -2 significa que vamos a reducir el triángulo 2 unidades (lados/2), por el contrario si factor = 2, significa que vamos a aumentar el triángulo 2 unidades (lados*2). Controlar las excepciones para cuando no se pueda reducir más el triángulo y para una posible división por cero (factor = 0).

Este es el código que he desarrollado hasta ahora:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Triangle6_h
#define Triangle6_h
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Triangle {
protected:
    int lado1, lado2, lado3;
public:
    Triangle() {
    }
    Triangle(int lado1, int lado2, int lado3) {
        this->lado1 = lado1;
        this->lado2 = lado2;
        this->lado3 = lado3;
    }
    void setLado1(int l1) {
        lado1 = l1;
    }
    int getLado1() {
        return lado1;
    }
    void setLado2(int l2) {
        lado2 = l2;
    }
    int getLado2() {
        return lado2;
    }
    void setLado3(int l3) {
        lado3 = l3;
    }
    int getLado3() {
        return lado3;
    }
    double area() {
        double s, area;
        s = (lado1 + lado2 + lado3) / 2;
        area = sqrt(s*(s - lado1)*(s - lado2)*(s - lado3));
        return area;
    }
    int perimetro() {
        return (lado1 + lado2 + lado3);
    }
    Triangle resize(int x) {
        int l1 = lado1;
        int l2 = lado2;
        int l3 = lado3;

        switch (x) {
        case(2):
            lado1 = (l1 * x);
            lado2 = (l2 * x);
            lado3 = (l3 * x);
            cout << "Lado 1: " << lado1 << "\nLado 2: " << lado2 << "\nLado 3: " << lado3 << endl;
            break;
        case(-2):
            lado1 = (l1 / x);
            lado2 = (l2 / x);
            lado3 = (l3 / x);
            cout << "Lado 1: " << lado1 << "\nLado 2: " << lado2 << "\nLado 3: " << lado3 << endl;
            break;
        }

    }
};
#endif /*Triangle6_h*/


#pragma once
#ifndef myexception1_h
#define myexception1_h
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class myexception : public exception
{
    virtual const char* what(int factor) const throw(){
        switch (factor) {
        case(0):
            return "Error: Uno de los lados tiene valor 0.";
            break;
        case(1):
            return "Error: Uno de los lados tiene valor negativo.";
            break;
        case(2):
            return "Error: Violacion de la desigualdad triangular.";
            break;
        case(3):
            return "Error: No se puede reducir mas el triangulo.";
            break;
        case(4):
            return "Error: Division por 0.";
        }
    }
};
#endif /*myexception1_h*/

#include <iostream>
#include "Triangle6.h"
#include "myexception1.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Triangle Tri(2,2,2);
    myexception myex;
    int a, b, c;

    cout << "Introduzca los tres lados de un triangulo: ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    bool flag = true;
    do {
        try {
            if (a == 0) {
                throw myex;
            }
            else if (b == 0) {
                throw myex;
            }
            else if (c == 0) {
                throw myex;
            }
            else {
                Tri.setLado1(a);
                Tri.setLado2(b);
                Tri.setLado3(c);
            }
        }
        catch (exception& e1) {
            cout << e1.what(0) << "Uno de los lados es 0." << '\n';
            flag = false;
        }

        try {
            if (a < 0) {
                throw myex;
            }
            else if (b < 0) {
                throw myex;
            }
            else if (c < 0) {
                throw myex;
            }
            else {
                Tri.setLado1(a);
                Tri.setLado2(b);
                Tri.setLado3(c);
            }
        }
        catch (exception& e2) {
            cout << e2.what(1) << "Uno de los lados es negativo." << '\n';
            flag = false;
        }

        try {
            if (a > b + c) {
                throw myex;
            }
            else if (b > a + c) {
                throw myex;
            }
            else if (c > a + b) {
                throw myex;
            }
            else {
                Tri.setLado1(a);
                Tri.setLado2(b);
                Tri.setLado3(c);
            }
        }
        catch (exception& e3) {
            cout << e3.what(2) << "La desigualdad triangular no se cumple." << '\n';
            flag = false;
        }
    } while (flag == true);
    return 0;
}
```

Por lo que sé a what() no se le pueden pasar parámetros, pero no se me ocurre otra manera para que imprimir las distintas excepciones con switch.

Comment: No acabo de entender cual es exactamente tu problema. ¿Quieres lanzar excepciones con parámetros?

Comment: @meegle84 Lo que quiero es que se impriman los mensajes para las diferentes excepciones, pero no se como hacerlo, es por eso que intenté hacerlo con parámetros, pero no se si así funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No te lies con las guardas

Las guardas son esas directivas de precompilador que se ponen en las cabeceras para que las mismas solo se carguen una vez. Si no se ponen las guardas el compilador encontrará declaraciones e implementaciones duplicadas y empezará a mostrar errores como si no hubiese un mañana.

La forma *estándar* de definir una guarda es:

```
#ifndef SIMBOLO_UNICO
#define SIMBOLO_UNICO

// contenido de la cabecera

#endif
```

Existe una forma alternativa bastante extendida pero que puede no estar soportada por algunos compiladores:

```
#pragma once
```

En tu caso estás usando ambas guardas:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Triangle6_h
#define Triangle6_h
```

Y eso no es necesario. Mi consejo es que dejes solo una de las dos. Bastante complejo puede llegar a ser ya un programa en C++ como para llenar el código de elementos que no aportan valor.

### Visibilidad y polimorfismo

La clase `myexception` no define una visibilidad explícita, así que sus miembros usarán la visibilidad por defecto.

`class` usa `private` como visibilidad por defecto, mientras que `struct` usa `public`. Esta es, de hecho, la única diferencia entre `struct` y `class`.

Dado que tu has usado `class`, el método `what` **es privado** y no puede usarse directamente:

```
myexception exc;
std::cout << exc.what(2); // Error: what es privado
```

Ahora bien, `std::exception` define `what` como `virtual`. Esto quiere decir que cualquier clase hija puede sobreescribir su comportamiento...  pero tenemos un problema en este punto y es que la función `what` de `std::exception` **no tiene parámetros**, mientras que la de `myexception` sí. Esto quiere decir que la función de `myexception` **es diferente** a la declarada en `std::exception`.

Llegados a este punto hay que destacar que aunque la clase base `std::exception` retorne un `const char *`, nosotros a nivel interno podemos usar los tipos de datos que mejor se adapten a nuestra necesidades. Solo tenemos que cuidar que `what` devuelva un mensaje en formato `const char*`.

Yo, personalmente, para estos casos prefiero usar `std::string` por varias razones:

- El código queda más limpio.
- Trabajar con `std::string` es más sencillo que usar `const char*`.
- El código es más seguro y menos problemático.

Ahora bien, ¿Cómo convertimos `std::string` en `const char*`? Para responder a esta pregunta tenemos que conocer la función `c_str()`. Esta función nos devuelve un puntero de tipo `char*` a la memoria interna de `std::string`:

```
class myexception : public std::exception
{
  std::string msg;
  
public:
    myexception(std::string msg)
      : msg(msg)
    { }
    
    char const* what() const noexcept override
    //                       ~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~ C++11
    {
      return msg.c_str();
    }
};
```

Como puedes ver, la excepción recibe el mensaje **en el constructor** y la razón es sencilla de entender. ¿En qué momento tienes toda la información sobre un problema, en el momento en el que se produce o en cualquier otro momento? Pues eso, la información sobre qué ha sucedido la tienes en el momento en el que se genera un problema y es ahí donde generas tu excepción con todo lujo de detalles... luego lanzas la excepción y quien la recibe (donde quiera que esté el receptor), puede analizar esos detalles para saber qué es lo que ha pasado.

Si el receptor ya tuviese toda la información entonces la excepción no sería necesaria... si yo ya se que se ha producido un error no necesito que nadie me lo notifique.

### Cada cosa en su lugar

Tu función `main`, en cuanto a excepciones se refiere, se está encargando absolutamente de todo. Lanza excepciones y las gestiona. Ese diseño no es consistente. Quien debería saber si los datos introducidos son válidos es la clase `Triangle`, así que debería ser ella la que lanzase, cuando proceda, las excepciones.

Debido a esto se hace recomendable relizar ciertos cambios en la interfaz de `Triangle`:

```
class Triangle {
private:
    int lados[3];
    
public:
    Triangle()
    {
    }

    void setLados(int l1, int l2, int l3)
    {
        // funcion declarada en <tuple> (C++11)
        std::tie(lados[0],lados[1],lados[2]) = std::tie(l1,l2,l3);
        
        // alternativa
        /*
        lados[0] = l1;
        lados[1] = l2;
        lados[2] = l3;
        */
        
        for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
        {
          if( lados[i] == 0 )
            throw myexception("Uno de los lados es 0.");
          else if( lados[i] < 0 )
            throw myexception("Uno de los lados es negativo.");
          else if( lados[i] > lados[(i+1)%3] + lados[(i+2)%3] )
            throw myexception("La desigualdad triangular no se cumple.");
        }
    }
    
    int getLado1() const
    {
        return lados[0];
    }
    
    int getLado2() const
    {
        return lados[1];
    }
    
    int getLado3() const
    {
        return lados[2];
    }
    
    double area() const
    {
        double s, area;
        s = (getLado1() + getLado2() + getLado3()) / 2;
        area = sqrt(s*(s - getLado1())*(s - getLado2())*(s - getLado3()));
        return area;
    }
    
    int perimetro() const
    {
        return (getLado1() + getLado2() + getLado3());
    }
    
    void resize(int x) {

        switch (x) {
        case(2):
            for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
              lados[i] *= x;

            break;
        case(-2):
             for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
              lados[i] /= x;

            break;
        }

        cout << "Lado 1: " << getLado1() << "\nLado 2: " << getLado2() << "\nLado 3: " << getLado3() << endl;
    }
};
```

La lista de cambios es amplia:

- La clase lanza las excepciones cuando las detecta
- `resize` no retorna nada
- Los métodos de consulta pasan a ser `const`
- Se elimina un constructor que no tiene sentido

Y con esto ya solo faltaría adaptar el `main`:

```
int main() {
    Triangle tri;
  
    bool repetir;
    do {
      repetir = false;
      
      cout << "Introduzca los tres lados de un triangulo: ";
      int a, b, c;
      cin >> a >> b >> c;

      try
      {
        tri.setLados(a,b,c);
      }
      
      catch( std::exception const& e)
      {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
        repetir = true;
      }
    } while( repetir );
    return 0;
}
```

No se si se nota, pero ahora queda ligeramente más limpio.

Answer (score 4):

En los comentarios:

> Lo que quiero es que se impriman los mensajes para las diferentes excepciones, pero no se como hacerlo

La manera de lanzar una excepción es:

```
throw objeto_excepcion;
```

La manera de capturar una excepción es:

```
try
{
    // Código que lanza excepción
}
catch (const objeto_excepción &e)
{
    // Código para manejar la excepción, incluidos mensajes.
}
```

Por lo tanto este código:

```
struct patata : public std::exception {};
struct frita : public std::exception {};
struct con : public std::exception {};
struct ketchup : public std::exception {};
struct y : public std::exception {};
struct mayonesa : public std::exception {};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw mayonesa{};
    }
    catch (const patata &e)
    {
        std::cout << "patata";
    }
    catch (const frita &e)
    {
        std::cout << "patata frita";
    }
    catch (const con &e)
    {
        std::cout << "patata frita con";
    }
    catch (const ketchup &e)
    {
        std::cout << "patata frita con ketchup";
    }
    catch (const y &e)
    {
        std::cout << "patata frita con ketchup y";
    }
    catch (const mayonesa &e)
    {
        std::cout << "patata frita con ketchup y mayonesa";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Imprimirá `patata frita con ketchup y mayonesa` porque se ha lanzado una excepción de tipo `mayonesa`.

#### A tener en cuenta.

- Puedes lanzar las excepciones que quieras, pero la captura debe ser una referencia constante al tipo lanzado para evitar copias, no lances (`throw`) punteros, menos aún si son punteros a memoria dinámica.
- Si lanzas una excepción en el constructor de un objeto, debes capturarla en el constructor usando un bloque `try`-`catch` a nivel de función:

  ```
  Objeto::Objeto() try
  {
  }
  catch( ... )
  {
  }
  ```